Para que se usa el arroba en PHP
Buen Día.-
Alguien me puede decir para que se usa el arroba en el lenguaje PHP.
Gracias por adelantado.

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. No incluyas etiquetas que no correspondan a la pregunta solo para "atraer más vistas". 2. Antes de formular una pregunta, revisa siempre que la pregunta no se haya hecho previamente en el sitio.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

En PHP, el símbolo @ se conoce como operador de control de errores. Este operador permite ignorar errores de php.
Mas detalles aquí:
¿Para que sirve la @ en PHP?
y acá: https://www.jesustovar.es/veteasabertu/simbolo-arroba-en-variables-php 
y acá: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php
y de ejemplo:
<?php

/* Intentional file error */
$my_file = @file ('non_existent_file') or die ("Failed opening file: error was '$php_errormsg'");

// this works for any expression, not just functions: 
$value = @$cache[$key];
// will not issue a notice if the index $key doesn't exist.

?>

